# Facebook Share Dialog, user message not being passed through

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Having issues getting the Share Dialog to work properly. My code is as follows (in [slim](http://slim-lang.com/)):

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title test page!!!

    javascript:
      window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
          appId: 'xxx',
          xfbml: true,
          version: 'v2.2'
        });
      };

      (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
          return;
        }
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  body
    h1 Facebook custom share button test

    a href='#' Testing!!

    javascript:
      document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
        FB.ui({ method: 'share', href: 'http://www.washingtonpost.com' }, function(resp) {});
        return false;
      });
```

My app setting on Facebook (development app) are setup correct (Site URL is set to `http://localhost:3000/`).

In summary, everything ***works*** except for the message that the user can type into the dialog here:

[image: share dialog]

That value never shows up when the post reaches the user's timeline feed:

[image: user profile]

I think I'm following [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) correctly. What am I missing?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in sdk!

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/395435640603415/